# bower install command issuing EHTTP error

Tags: npm, bower, ember-cli

I am struggling with installing bower on my system - although there are a few bower install issue scenarios on here, none are a very good match.

In my scenario, I have an externally acquired folder full of source code for a complex software package - the .bowerrc file is located here, as well as a bower.json. As is the default, my .npmrc file is located C:\Users\USER.

I have appended code strict-ssl=false and registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/ into .npmjs, and left the npm cache and config specs in the user directory. I've also left my PATH user variable as C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm.

I have so far run three commands successfully:

```
npm install -g ember-cli
npm install -g bower
npm install
```

The created files from these commands seem to get dumped into C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules, and then the final command below is only giving me an EHTTP error.

```
bower install
```

I can only think that this issue is only occurring because of the location of the various dependencies. I've been playing around a bit - the last thing I tried was changing the Path user variable so that it instead points to the folder directory with .bowerrc, but the npm installation then has trouble referencing .npmrc. I'd appreciate any ideas, because I might only be chasing my own tail here.

**UPDATE**

I think I was wasting my time messing about with directory locations. The problem seems to be that there is a legacy proxy inside the .bowerrc file.. now I just need to work out how to get rid of the proxy setting!